# Cpanel - Domain is redirecting to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, cpanel

I have a domain https://domain.com.au. It is working a week before. Now it redirects to https://dev8.domain.com.au.

I have checked the cpanel for redirections but there is no redirects created.
I also checked .htaccess file

```
  # BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
  # Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
  # To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
  # For more information, read our documentation 
  (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
  <IfModule php7_module>
    php_flag display_errors Off
    php_value max_execution_time 30
    php_value max_input_time 60
    php_value max_input_vars 5000
    php_value memory_limit 384M
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
    php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70"
    php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

I can access folders in https://domain.com.au/ like wp-admin and wp-includes.

[image]

Comment: Check the Wordpress base URL.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think "https://dev8.domain.com.au" is not a redirect but a sub domain of "https://domain.com.au". I'd say double check your sub-domains to make sure it isn't installed on one of them.